# Securing php script from sql injection

Tags: mysql, sqlmap

my friends website got hacked, the hacker leak all of the database data using SQLMAP from `http://example.com/users/users.php?id=3` what methods exist in php to avoid writing vulnerable code like this?

Comment: Covered pretty well on Stack Overflow: [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Security.SE. The issue isn't `sqlmap`, but SQL injection.

### What is SQL Injection?

SQL injection is a vulnerability that allows an attacker to control the data in and out of the database. This is how your friend's site was broken in to.

### How do I protect against SQL injection?

The universal fix is to use parameterized queries. How this is done depends on the language that is used. For PHP, the PDO library supports this.

### Additional reading material

- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_injection